# Remerge after reverting failed merge

Tags: git, git-merge, git-revert

I have two branches in repository: *feature* and *master*. I have merged master into feature and pushed result to remote *feature* branch:

```
git merge master
```

because it contains necessary changes of external interfaces. Than I have discovered that merge conflicts were resolved wrong and I have reverted this merge with:

```
git revert -n -m 1 78e7ebfa8237
```

So I'm back on *feature* not merged. But according to history merge already happened and feature branch already contains necessary changes. Can I try merge branches again (inspecting conflicts more carefully and not commiting before checking build)?

Comment: git reset --hard  helps you to revert recent merged code, then see the log ,where HEAD is the last commit in your current branch. Then you can merge again.

Comment: This answer may helps you: [How to revert to a previous commit][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-a-previous-git-commit

Comment: Yes, it reverts commit if it was not pushed to remote. But it's not my case - merge was pushed to remote, so I had to revert it. Sorry, didn't mentioned it.

Comment: Oh, you have to revert using commit id (hash-key.) First step: revert to original condition for feature branch
Second step: merge again with master branch. (I guess you have not touched master branch yet. )

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have *not* published the bad merge and its reversion, you can remove them and publish a correct merge instead.

If you *have* published (pushed or otherwise given out) the bad merge, your best bet is probably to work out a correct merge by creating a new branch starting from just before the bad merge.  For instance, suppose the commit graph fragment looks like this:

```
...--i--j--m--w   <-- feature
          /
...---k--l        <-- master
```

where merge commit `m` is the one that went wrong, and `w` (`m` upside down<sup>1</sup>) is the reversion of `m`.  (Note: if you have a more complex history, you probably should use a different strategy; see the link in the footnote.)

Here, the idea would be to check out commit `j` directly:

```
git checkout <sha1-of-j>
```

You are now in "detached HEAD" mode.  At this point you can run a new `git merge`:

```
git merge master
```

This will (based on your mention of merge conflicts) stop with a merge conflict, since it's repeating the step that got you bad-merge-`m`.  (If it won't stop on its own, add `--no-commit` to the merge command.)

Now resolve the conflicts correctly this time :-) and `add` and `commit` as needed.  This makes a new merge which I'll call `M`, and I will draw the new graph like this:

```
...--i--j------m--w   <-- feature
         \    /
          M  /        <-- HEAD
          | /
         / /
         |/
...---k--l            <-- master
```

This new commit `M` is not (yet) on any branch, and in fact, you don't really need it to be on any branch: what you want is the *tree* you obtained at this point.

Now we'll make this a new (but temporary) branch to remember the SHA-1 of commit `M`:

```
git checkout -b temp
```

(we could have done this earlier; you can do it at the "check out commit `j`" step if you like; but I have some other, un-tested, methods in mind that I'll outline below).  Now let's get back on `feature` and make a new commit that uses `M`'s tree, rather than that of `m` or `w`.  There are several ways to do this, but I will illustrate this one since it's pretty simple:

```
git checkout feature
git rm -r .  # assumes you're in the top level of the work dir
git checkout temp -- .
```

The first of these, `checkout feature`, simply gets us back on branch `feature`.  The second empties out the index (the "next commit")—this step is only necessary if `M` is missing some file(s) that are in `m` and `w`—and then the third extracts the entire tree from commit `M` into the index and work-tree.

Now we're ready to commit the result:

```
git commit -m "replace everything with corrected merge"
```

The graph now looks like this:

```
...--i--j------m--w--n   <-- HEAD=feature
         \    /
          M  /           <-- temp
          | /
         / /
         |/
...---k--l               <-- master
```

The files under commit `n` are the same as those under commit `M`.  We no longer need commit `M` and branch `temp` at all, so we can simply delete them (`git branch -D temp`), giving:

```
...--i--j--m--w--n   <-- HEAD=feature
          /
...---k--l           <-- master
```

---

If you're comfortable with using lower level git commands, there's a simpler (?) way to copy the tree from `M` to a new commit we'll put on `feature`.  In particular we just need to make a new commit whose parent is `w` and whose tree is that of `M`.  We can do that in one step while still on `M` and the anonymous HEAD, with `git commit-tree`:

```
id=$(git commit-tree -p feature -m "message" $(git rev-parse HEAD^{tree}))
```

Assuming this works (I haven't tested this particular form and you might have to use `git rev-parse` to convert the name `feature` to a raw SHA-1), we can then use `git update-ref` to make `refs/heads/feature` contain id `$id`:

```
git update-ref -m "add corrected merge" refs/heads/feature $id
```

after which it's safe to simply `git checkout feature` to get back on the (updated) branch.

This being git, there are more ways to do it, e.g., when on the anonymous branch, you could do this:

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/feature
git commit -m "replace everything with corrected merge"
```

which is probably simpler than the `git commit-tree` method (the `commit-tree` method is just what I thought of first, due to having recently written a complicated shell script that used `commit-tree` for a fancy repo shadowing thing).  The way this works is that the `symbolic-ref` puts you back on branch `feature` but does not touch the index (nor work-tree) at all, so it/they still match the tree for commit `M`.  Then we make a new commit in the ordinary way, using the current index; and since nothing remains to point to commit `M`, the garbage-collector will eventually delete that commit (but not the tree itself, which is now safely saved on branch `feature`).

---

<sup>1</sup>The `m` and `w` thing is [stolen directly from Linus Torvalds and Junio Hamano](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt).

Comment: THANK YOU a billion times ! Very clear. I was pulling my hairs for days trying to `git checkout` file one by one and nothing would work !

Comment: An alternative once you have your `M` commit is to simply cherry-pick it into the feature branch.
```bash
git checkout feature
git cherry-pick -m 1 COMMIT_HASH
```
where `COMMIT_HASH` is the hash of `M`

Answer (score 1):

If you execute the git revert, it will undo the merge, so I do not think the feature contains necessary changes. I will goes to the state before merge only with some additional git log. So you can freely merge it.
But, if you do not want the additional git log, you can use git reset.

1. Check which is your wanted previous state:`git log`
2. `git reset {commit-id-founded}`
3. resolve your conflicts
4. merge again

Comment: That's really simple! I didn't know that I can merge from detached state.

Comment: What about if have new commits to this branch? They wouldn't be saved anymore.